# FireBase stuck on "Run your app to verify installation" for android

Tags: android, firebase

I'm new to android development, since a long time, I'm stuck in one error that is Run your app to verify installation (Checking if the app has communicated with our servers. You may need to uninstall and reinstall your app.)

```
build.gradle(Module:app)
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    }

     dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
```

Comment: I think you forgot the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` part to be added just below and outside the dependencies section

Comment: For me on VScode with reactnative the issue was double quotes on this plugin. When I did apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services" instead of apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' it worked

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have to do nothing for your question but run the app on the android emulator or a real android device. If you have made your app and later added the `dependencies`, then you need to delete the app from the device/emulator and install the app again.

By doing this, when the app runs, it passes variables from the `google-services.json` file to the firebase servers and checks if the same app is communicating or not.

This step is to verify the correct installation of firebase dependencies in the app. If you find it difficult, you can skip the process anyway.

Comment: As a side note, if your firebase dependencies are not up to date, updating them will help as well.

Answer (score 20):

Thanks to @Udayraj Deshmukh comment I fixed the issue.
I thought I will add this as an answer as it helped me

Simply go to your app-level Gradle and add this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[image]

Firebase SDK guide forgot to tell you to include the plugin.
[image]

Comment: If you got a solution from a comment, then your answer should be [made *community wiki* to avoid downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741)

Comment: +1 it solved!!! but i also have to change my gms and analytic version to the ones showing in console (previous was higher). And it only work when i run with device not emulator. So strange

Answer (score 16):

I followed every step, but i didn't work. So I contacted the Firebase support and got the following answer:

> Thanks for reaching out, Simon.
>
> I'd recommend just skipping that step altogether. The app should have
>   already been successfully added and to verify that Firebase is
>   working, it'd be better to directly test whichever service you're
>   trying to use.
>
> Let me know if you have any other questions/issues.

---- Update 2020-01-20 ----

I found out that someone of my colleagues added this snippet in the AndroidManifest.xml a couple of years ago. After enabling analytics again I got the expected behaviour in the Firebase console.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated"
    android:value="true" />
```

Answer (score 12):

In my case the problem was that in the gradle file at project level, I had set the latest google-services, which at the time of this answer is **4.3.0**:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

Then I noticed that in the Firebase wizard, the configuration steps showed instead a previous version: **4.2.0**

Changing my gradle one to match the same version as shown in the Firebase configuration wizard solved the problem.

Note: so, **my conclusion is that regardless of which one is the latest google-services version, (and the versions we talk about in this stack-overflow question and answer), we should always use the version shown in the Firebase wizard configuration steps**.

Comment: That was a my case!
After analytics got confirmation that app is added I just reverted back to the 4.3.0 version and it works!

Comment: Now it recommends me **4.3.2** but still just **4.2.0** is working!!!!

Answer (score 8):

If the application is still empty, you need to add internet permission in the manifest.
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you don't have any network-level adblockers running, which may be blocking calls to Firebase.

In my case, I had to disable Pi-Hole in order to allow my app to connect to Firebase over my network.

Comment: in my case i had to disable AdGuard

Answer (score 3):

I solved updating the SDK Tools: **Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Updates**, then click on "Check Now".

When the update was completed I uninstalled the app from the emulator, quitted both Android Studio and emulator and ran again

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue, i deleted the google.json / google.plist file and started the app again. clean the build folder, clear caches, delete the app off simulator, restart it, do pod update && pod install... etc. I found for me this happened when the google file was messed up

Answer (score 2):

Just run `flutter clean` command in Android studio terminal, then reinstall and then try connecting it in firebase it will work

Answer (score 2):

None of the above answers helped me. But @kotlinski's answer helped me to go AndroidManifest.xml to check issue. In my case, this was the entry in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
        android:value="false" />
```

I just modified it to true, in order to make things work. Immediately I got message on FCM console *'Congratulations, you've successfully added Firebase to your app!*
'

Answer (score 1):

In my case `Fabric` was conflicting with `Firebase`. When i removed Fabric from packages, it started working.
Also i have seen cases when there is problem to verify, when phone is connected to `wifi`. In this case change network to `Mobile data`.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you:**

1. Have included google() in the **buildscript** repositories in the android/build.gradle
2. Have added **classpath** 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3' dependency in the android/build.gradle
3. Have included google() in the **allprojects** repositories in the android/build.gradle

And [this official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android#add-config-file) helped me a lot (I just followed all the steps).

Answer (score 0):

If any one is getting like this in console :

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key. ]
```

Just change the version of google services at project level gradle and sync your project and reinstall.

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'

This work for me 
I

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is not good for analytics. google merge Google Analytics with firebase from then this irritating issue occurred. Previously Google analytics was working superbly within sec. Now we don't have options just skip this step and hope it'll work automatically after sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the exact version mentioned in Waizard, It will show success.

Its worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found that, even though I wasn't using Analytics (only functions and firestore), I had to add the analytics line in the build.gradle file, or:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
```

in order for the automatic app detection to work.

I think if you know what you are doing, and don't need analytics, it is fine to just skip this step.

Answer (score -1):

You are not stucked my friend, just follow this steps:
1. Go to your android studio project and click on Main_activity.xml to show your app
2. click run menu and run the app either in a real device or an emulator
3. when it has loaded the app, then your connection will be successful in firebase

Comment: same problem, I have run the app but it still says " Checking if the app has communicated with our servers. You may need to uninstall and reinstall your app. "

Comment: @Gourav no, it still say "checking.." I have uninstalled and reinstalled, the app, delete it from firebase and added again..

Answer (score -3):

Incase you are running the app in a physical android device ensure it has the same google account as used to sign up for Firebase.