# Errors in adding firebase to flutter in android studio on Mac OS: Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found. Please update settings.gradle

Tags: firebase, android-studio, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to link my flutter app to firebase and I added all the plugins that I need firebase_core, cloud_firestore and firebase_auth at the latest versions. I also added the Jason file as instructed in the fire base website when creating the project. The problem is when I run it, it takes a very long time to finish running (in fact I never saw it finish running after adding the plugins) and that I always get this error

```
Plugin project :cloud_firestore_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :firebase_auth_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
```

I tried following these links and I still get this error https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2599
[FireBase stuck on "Run your app to verify installation" for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55159894/firebase-stuck-on-run-your-app-to-verify-installation-for-android/55161810)

Comment: upgrade your plugins ,this should not stop your project from running else install the above plugins from pub.dev

Comment: example https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore_web